# How would I create a duplicate category and delete the original category in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I currently have a command which will clone and delete a specific channel using message context:

```py
@bot.command(name="refresh=", aliases=["refresh"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def refresh(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.clone(reason="refresh channel command")
    await ctx.channel.delete()
```

But I would like to be able to do this for a whole category.

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no API method to clone an entire category so I am wondering how to do this via another method.

Answer (score 0):

There is according to the [API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.category)

i believe it would be

```
await ctx.category.clone()
```

and

```
await ctx.category.delete()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as much as I wished this was the solution and having already tried it I reached out here for help. `ctx.category` does not exist, you have to use the `CategoryChannel` class but I do not understand how to accomplish what I am trying to do with it.

When attempting to `ctx.category.clone()` it simply errors out with `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'category'`